# cant fix Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: codeigniter-3, alertifyjs

Hello im beginner at javascript and jquery and I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

I don't know how to solve this. What to do to fix this error?

Here is my js file:

```
var fname, lname, organization, designation, email, m_number;
$('#proceedBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    fname = $('#fname').val();
    lname = $('#lname').val();
    email = $('#email').val();
    phone = $('#m_number').val();
    organization = $('#organization').val();
    designation = $('#designation').val();
    //set it to true
    var isProceed = true;

    if (fname.trim() === "" || fname.length < 2) {
        alertify.error('Please input your first name');
        isProceed = false;
    }

    if (lname.trim() === "" || lname.length < 2) {
        alertify.error('Please input your last name');
        isProceed = false;
    }
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var emailValid = re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());

    if (email.trim() === "" || email.length < 3 || !emailValid) {
        alertify.error('Please check your email');
        isProceed = false;
    }

    if (m_number === "" || m_number.length < 3) {
        alertify.error('Please input your phone');
        isProceed = false;
    }
    if (organization.trim() === "" || organization.length < 2) {
        alertify.error('Please input your organization');
        isProceed = false;
    }

    if (designation.trim() === "" || designation.length < 2) {
        alertify.error('Please input your designation');
        isProceed = false;
    }


    if (isProceed) {
        procceedBTN();
        // $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 0);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initiated some variables in the top, but not defined/assigned any value to them

> var fname, lname, organization, designation, email, m_number;

note that, these variables have value undefined

in the starting of your function, you assigned some values to fname, lname and email, But still m_number is undefined.

In your whole code you never assigned any value to m_number

but in your code at:

```
 if (m_number === "" || m_number.length < 3) {
    alertify.error('Please input your phone');
    isProceed = false;
}
```

you are asking to check the length of an undefined variable

```
m_number.length //this is the error
```

You can simply remove this part of code or can define a value to m_number

Like

```
m_number = ''
```

Comment: thank you ZeevhY.Org. the error is gone.

Comment: My Pleasure, hope you also hit the like button to vote and express this answer to helpful

Comment: Org how to find the like button? XD im totally new to this stuffs, i cant find it

Answer (score 0):

just change 'phone' to 'm_number'

Comment: Thank you. i didtn see it